# SQL function to split dates between first half of the month(1 to 15) and second half of the month(16 to 30/31)

Tags: sql

suppose I am passing startDat='2020-03-31 00:00:00.000' Enddate:'2020-04-21 00:00:00.000' so expected output is;

```
from_date                          to_date
-----------                       ------------
2020-03-31                         2020-03-31
2020-04-01                         2020-04-15
2020-04-16                         2020-04-21
```

Comment: Is that the expected result? From what table data?

Comment: When does the second half of a month begin?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: I want the result in table format. I am passing start date and end date to the function. I am creating sql function. sql database.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, just after the first half ends.

Comment: @Priyanka, show us some more examples of input and expected output. And define first and second half.

Comment: suppose I am passing startDat='2020-03-31 00:00:00.000' Enddate:'2020-04-21 00:00:00.000' so exepected output is;

from_date                          to_date
-----------                       ------------
2020-03-31                         2020-03-31

2020-04-01                         2020-04-15

2020-04-16                         2020-04-21

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Since months are static, what you could do is have variables that has the starting half of each month, and then variables with the end date of each month. If it's from a dynamic data set you simply make case when statements on the months and use the variables in that way.

Comment: What about February? Is 15 the middle of that month as well, or perhaps 14 (or 14.5 in leap years)

Comment: for February 15 is the middle of month not 14.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE = '03-31-2020'
DECLARE @Date2 DATE = '04-21-2020'
DECLARE @Day INT = 0
DECLARE @Month INT = 0
DECLARE @Year INT = 0
DECLARE @MidDayofMonth INT = 15
DECLARE @EOM INT 
DECLARE @table TABLE (StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE)
WHILE @Date1 <= @Date2
BEGIN
    SET @Day =  DATEPART(DAY,@Date1)
    SET @Month = DATEPART(MONTH,@Date1)
    SET @Year = DATEPART(YEAR,@Date1)
    IF @Day < 15
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT CASE WHEN  @Day < 15
                THEN @Date1
            END AS StartDate,
            CASE WHEN @Date1 < @date2 AND  @Date2 > CONCAT(@Month,'-',@MidDayofMonth,'-',@Year)  
            THEN CONCAT(@Month,'-',@MidDayofMonth,'-',@Year) 
            ELSE @Date2 END
            AS EndDate
    SET @Date1 = DATEADD(DAY,1,CONCAT(@Month,'-',@MidDayofMonth,'-',@Year))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT @Date1 AS StartDate,
            CASE WHEN @Date1 <= @date2 AND  @Date2 > EOMONTH(@Date1) 
            THEN EOMONTH(@Date1) 
            ELSE @Date2 END
             AS EndDate
    SET @Date1 = DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@date1))
    END
END
SELECT * FROM @table
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJYZR.png)